# Filtering in HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Let's assume I have a Node class

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name;
    public ObservableCollection<Node> SubNodes;
}
```

and created following xaml to visualize collection of Node objects:

```
<TreeView Name="Tree">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="myNamespace:Node" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubNodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

in the codebehind I write something like

```
Tree.ItemsSource = my_Observable_Collection_Of_Nodes;
```

and enjoy the result.

Now I want to apply my own filtering function (say "MyFilterFun") to all Nodes in the tree view. To this end I've modified HierarchicalDataTemplate to something like

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="myNamespace:MyClass">
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Source>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=SubNodes}"
                    Filter="MyFilterFun"/>
            </BindingSource>
        </Binding>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Unfortunately this does not work, "MyFilterFun" is never called.
So what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Have property of type `CollectionViewSource` or `ICollectionView` in underlying source class and bind with that property.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by using an ICollectionView. From your ObservableCollection you could do something like:

```
SubNodesCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SubNodes);
SubNodesCollectionView.Filter = (param) => 
{ 
    return true; 
};
```

Then bind to SubNodesCollectionView instead of SubNodes. The lambda handler will be a method that you can specify to filter each by instead of just returning true.